# Parsing Quotes using a SLR/LR/LALR Parser

Tags: string, parsing, compiler-construction

I'm trying to parse a list that is separated by spaces, but may include quotes that I have to treat as literals. So I tried to write a grammar and parse it using my favorite parsing algorithm, but I can't seem to get the grammar right.

The particular thing that makes it tricky is that I have to handle the `" "" "` case, which should be interpreted as one string with two quotes, whereas `"" ""` should be two empty strings.

To make the problem worse, I have to handle single quotes `' '` and comments bracketed by `* *`. Things like: `' * ' " * ' "` are allowed, which should parse to `*` and `* '`.

Is this just outright impossible or is there a grammar to do it?

The best try I've managed to come up with (`_` denotes space):

```
start -> argv $
argv -> argv _ term | term
term -> "" | '' | ** | "dqexpr" | 'sqexpr' | *comment* | expr
expr -> string without ", ', *, or _
dqexpr -> string without "
sqexpr -> string without '
comment -> string without *
```

But I can't be make this work on `" "" "` with a LR(1)/SLR(1) parser.

The grammar I attempted, for the simple case with no comments and only one quote type:

```
START -> ARGV $
ARGV -> ARGV _ TERM
ARGV -> TERM
TERM -> q STRING q
TERM -> FREE
STRING -> STRING CHAR
CHAR -> ''
CHAR -> q
CHAR -> c
FREE -> FREE c
FREE -> c
```

Here, `''` is epsilon; `q` represents a quote, `_` a space, and `c` any other character. The grammar can be attempted using the on-line tool at http://jsmachines.sourceforge.net/machines/slr.html

Comment: Works fine for me. Can you paste the real grammar you wrote which you claim doesn't work?

Comment: @rici I used the grammar at http://pastebin.com/e1E5ENcT to try to solve the simplified problem, where we have single quotes only. Here, q is stands for quote and c is a generic character, '' is epsilon.

I used http://jsmachines.sourceforge.net/machines/slr.html

to generate the SLR parser. This parser to parse q q q _ c even though it has a legal parse.

Comment: In your question, you say that `" "" "` is "one string with two quotes", while in your comment above you suggest that `""" c` should be valid. Neither of those seem right to me, particularly the second one. How would you quote a string which contains a quote followed by a space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `STRING` non-terminal in your attempted grammar is *useless* (that is, it cannot derive any string of terminals) because it has no non-recursive production. So a parser generator should discard it, along with the `TERM -> q STRING q` production. (Ideally, an error message to that effect would be generated.) If that were fixed, the production `CHAR -> ''` would generate an ambiguity, because a `STRING` can be any number of `CHAR`s, and you cannot tell how many epsilons there are in an empty string. Ideally, the parser generator would provide meaningful error messages although, as can be seen, not all do so.

That can be fixed by simply changing `CHAR -> ''` to `STRING -> ''`, which will also solve the conflict generated by the ambiguity of concatenating two epsilons. What remains is allowing a quoted `STRING` to contain a `q`, which contradicts the description in the pseudocode ("`dqexpr -> string without "`").

If the intention is to allow a term to be a concatenation of quoted strings, so that `" "" "` is valid (without entering into its semantics), that can be done by adding another iteration non-terminal:

```
QTERMS -> QTERM
QTERMS -> QTERMS QTERM
QTERM  -> q STRING q
```

and changing `TERM -> q STRING q` to `TERM -> QTERM`.

My suspicion is that the desire is a simplified form of shell word processing, in which a "word" can be a concatenation of any number of terms, so that not only is `" "" "` a legal word, but so are `" "' '` and `"x"foo'y'`. This allows the possibility to include both single and double quotes in the same word: `"'"'"'`. If we also make the assumption that a comment is equivalent to white-space, we end up with the following grammar:

```
START -> ARGV $
ARGV -> WORD
ARGV -> ARGV WHITES WORD
WHITES -> WHITE
WHITES -> WHITES WHITE
WHITE -> _
WHITE -> star CSTRING star
WORD -> TERM
WORD -> WORD TERM
TERM -> c
TERM -> squote SQSTRING squote
TERM -> dquote DQSTRING dquote
SQSTRING -> ''
SQSTRING -> SQSTRING c
SQSTRING -> SQSTRING _
SQSTRING -> SQSTRING star
SQSTRING -> SQSTRING dquote
DQSTRING -> ''
DQSTRING -> DQSTRING c
DQSTRING -> DQSTRING _
DQSTRING -> DQSTRING star
DQSTRING -> DQSTRING squote
CSTRING  -> ''
CSTRING  -> CSTRING c
CSTRING  -> CSTRING _
CSTRING  -> CSTRING squote
CSTRING  -> CSTRING squote
```

The [SLR tool](http://jsmachines.sourceforge.net/machines/slr.html) you use successfully generates a parser using the above grammar.

Comment: I appreciate the attempt. I think this is probably the best we can do. I'm starting to become convinced what I'm trying to do is not in the world of LR parsers. `squote dquote squote dquote squote` fails to parse even though there is a valid interpretation: 1 string of " ' ". In fact, if we have k characters of lookahead, I can just nest the " ' " pattern k+1 times. Thus, I've just accepted your answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @avak: I'm not convinced that there is a valid interpretation of that string. (Or more precisely, if there is a valid interpretation, then there are strings which have multiple valid interpretations.) One of the points of a grammar is to be *precise* about the structure of a language in a way in which informal descriptions or collections of examples cannot be. If a grammar consistently shows an ambiguity, it is quite possible that the language you are trying to express is actually not well defined.

Comment: @avak: The question I raise in my comment to your post stands: If you allow a word containing an odd number of delimiting quotes, you need to understand under what circumstances an interior delimiting quote is a delimiter. If the condition is that it is a delimiter if it is followed by a space, then you have no way to express a word which contains a delimiting quote followed by a space. I know of no formalism which attempts this, precisely for that reason. Shells allow concatenation of quoted strings using different quotes; other formalisms use an escape character like \, or double delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

The grammar should actually be the same as matching parentheses, so you should be able to find lots of examples on parsing math expressions.

I'm not exactly sure what your example grammar is trying to accomplish but including "", '', and ** in your `term` rule seems odd to me. Try changing it to be something like:

```
expr -> string
expr -> ' string '
expr -> " string "
```

Comment: I don't think it's the same as the matching bracket problem. I have to deal with the " " " case, which should resolve to a single double quote.

Comment: @avak You should be able to do that using "left recursion."  The problem I see is that you may have ambiguities, which may be fine, you just need a rule to solve them.

Comment: Can you add more elaborate about "left recursion"?